# ¿Hay o ha habido algún intento de regularizar todos los verbos en español?

Tags: gramática, verbos, conjugación

Mi hijo de tres años está empezando a elaborar frases cada vez más complejas. Resulta fascinante comprobar cómo está interiorizando el concepto de conjugar los verbos, aunque él ni siquiera sepa lo que está haciendo. Lo gracioso viene cuando construye frases como las siguientes:

> ¿Me ayudas? Es que yo no *sabo*...
>   Mira, me lo he *ponido* yo solo.

Y claro, uno trata de corregirle mientras piensa en lo fácil que sería el español si los verbos se conjugaran todos de forma regular. Y ahí va entonces la pregunta:

- ¿Hay o ha habido algún intento serio de regularizar todas las conjugaciones de todos los verbos en español? Y con serio me refiero, por ejemplo, al estilo de la *[Ortografia kastellana, nueva i perfeta](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/%C3%8Dndice:Ortografia_kastellana,_nueva_i_perfeta.pdf)* que se publicó como libro en un intento de regularizar y simplificar la ortografía.
- Dado que ya existen verbos que admiten para determinados tiempos verbales una conjugación regular y otra irregular (como *freído* y *frito*), ¿qué dificultades habría para permitir ambas conjugaciones en todos los tiempos de todos los verbos? Por ejemplo, que no estuviera mal dicho *habiera* en vez de *hubiera*, y con la excepción tal vez de los verbos más básicos, como *ser*.
- ¿Tiene o ha tenido la RAE alguna vez alguna posición al respecto?

Answer (score 6):

El propio concepto de lengua como entidad viva impide regularizar artificial (y arbitrariamente) los verbos. Sería absurdo pretender hacer todos esos cambios desde una organización (llámese RAE o de otra forma). Solo los hablantes, a través de muchas generaciones, podrían cambiar eso.

Aquí hay que tener cuidado y no confundir la "regularización de la ortografía", pues la ortografía es una convención arbitraria y por tanto se puede modificar a antojo, con la "regularización de la morfología", que es una entidad viva y "orgánica" y por tanto no modificable por capricho.

Por cierto, el hecho de que tu hijo use formas regulares para verbos irregulares significa que ya está empezando a comprender la morfología y aplica las reglas correctamente (aunque a casos incorrectos). Va por el buen camino :)

Edito para citar [esta entrevista](http://www.jotdown.es/2017/04/ines-fernandez-ordonez-la-lengua-evoluciona-forma-natural-sistema-eficaz-todas-las-epocas/) que acaba de publicar *Jot Down*:

> *Respecto a la lengua estándar, ¿es cierta la afirmación de que «la lengua la hacen los hablantes»? ¿La norma es tan democrática o en realidad es una aristocracia, en el sentido etimológico de la palabra? Porque realmente manda más Varga Llosa que yo.*
>
> Mi opinión es que la estandarización que no esté basada en el uso no tiene posibilidad de prosperar. Si haces una recomendación de un uso basado en el de gente muy ilustre pero de empleo muy minoritario, no prospera. Lo hacen las que emanan de un uso general que se ha asentado en la lengua, porque en los cambios lingüísticos lo fundamental no son las minorías, son las clases medias. Esto lo han estudiado muy bien los sociolingüistas. Un cambio puede empezar en un grupo sociocultural marginado, pero no prospera si no prende en los grupos intermedios. Cuando penetra en las clase medias se difunde y gana la batalla. Lo mismo podemos decir respecto de un uso marginal de las clases altas, de individuos muy ilustres, que tienen un altavoz muy importante pero que no necesariamente consiguen que su práctica reciba el refrendo de la colectividad. Recomendar usos lingüísticos minoritarios que no están basados en el uso colectivo no tiene sentido.